# Is there a way to get all ongoing AsyncTasks?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am writing a few tests for Android code that does business logic and triggers asynchronous db operations through the Sprinkles library. My tests are basically failing when they expect certain data to be present in db, but the data is missing due to the async writes not being completed yet. Therefore, for testing purposes, it seems that I need a way to wait for the async jobs to be finished before I do my assertions.

After taking a look at how Sprinkles does the asynchronous writes, it simply triggers a new AsyncTask. But these AsyncTasks are completely handled by Sprinkles so I do not have access to them. So I was wondering: is there a way to get hold of all ongoing AsyncTasks started by my application? If there is, then I can make my tests wait for all AsyncTasks to be completed. Not a great solution, but it would do the trick.

Otherwise, does anyone have any tips on how to tackle this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> m = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
```

then go over each stack traces and look for async tasks and see if they are in

```
doInBackground
```

method

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar, I decided to keep Boolean variables to represent if they had completed or not. and check on the OnPostExecute method of every Async task if all had finished or not and if all had then set a boolean variable representing that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I do not have access to the the AsyncTasks since they are handle by an external library: Sprinkles. I will update my questions to clarify this. Thanks again!

Comment: if your asynctasks are being run serially(one at a time) you can just create another asynctask that will run after the others have completed